# Using matter physics for my 8ballpool remake and the ball is bouncing in very unexpected ways and I am not sure why

Tags: javascript, 2d, game-physics, phaser-framework, matter.js

Am new to Phaser so sorry if this seems like an obvious answer. I have two classes: one for my cueball (and other balls) and one for walls. I've added bounce to the ball and yet, sometimes it looks the ball bounces more than it should, other times it stops dead in its track when touching a wall, and when using max force the ball will sometimes go through the wall. To make the physics/collision border for the walls, I used the PhysicsEditor app and I'm not sure if that is causing the issues or if it's the code.
Here is my ball class:

```
export default class Ball extends Phaser.Physics.Matter.Sprite {
    constructor(world, x, y, spriteSheet, sprite, scene) {
        super(world, x, y, spriteSheet, sprite);
        this.setScale(0.35);
        this.setFriction(0.5);
        this.setCircle(11);
        this.setFixedRotation();
        this.setBounce(1);
        scene.add.existing(this);
    }

}
```

Here is my wall class:

```
export default class Wall extends Phaser.Physics.Matter.Sprite {
    constructor(world, x, y, spriteSheet, sprite, bodyConfig, scene, scale, needsRotation = false) {
        super(world, x, y, spriteSheet, sprite, bodyConfig);    
        this.setStatic(true);
        this.setScale(scale);
        this.setPosition(x, y);
        this.setAngle(needsRotation ? 180 : 0);

        scene.add.existing(this);
    }
    
}
```

And in my cue class is where I deal with adding force to the ball like so:

```
// Add power to ball when mouse button is released
this.scene.input.on('pointerup', function() {
    if (this.isDragging) {
        this.disableCue();
        const velocityVector = this.velocityVector(this.cueContainer.rotation, this.power);
        this.ball.setVelocity(-velocityVector.x, -velocityVector.y);
    }
    this.isDragging = false;
}, this)

// Calculates the vector needed for adding velocity in x and y directions
velocityVector(rotation, speed) {
    let x = Math.cos(rotation) * speed;
    let y = Math.sin(rotation) * speed;

    return new Phaser.Math.Vector2(x, y);
}
```

Here's a demo video to what I mean: https://youtu.be/nM6mWDI0oyo